# Creating your own custom RibbonControl type in Word VSTO

Tags: vsto, ribbon, office-addins

I have created a Word VSTO add-in. I would like to create a custom RibbonControl type in my add-in Ribbon, to show information to the users. It would only be text.

I have tried using "Label" or "EditBox" to the purpose, but it looks awful. I have also tried creating a custom control and implement the RibbonControl interface but it doesn't work.

I have used the designer way to create the ribbon. Can the XML method be used and how?

I have googled for hours and I am not sure that is is possible at all. Any clues?

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create your own custom ribbon controls, you are limited to the built-in controls.